# Matlab Blur Filter using Function

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make a function in Matlab that blurs my image. I'm using Matlabs demo image `peppers.png`.

Here is my function:

```
    function g = myfilter(f, h)

    f = double(f); %convert to double
    g = zeros(size(f)); %new array (size of f)
    a = (size(h, 1) - 1) / 2; %padding on edges

    for row = (a + 1) : (size(f,1) - a)
        for col = (a + 1) : (size(f,2) - a)

            gxy = 0; %running sum

            for m = -a:a
                for n = -a:a

                    gxy = gxy + f(row - m, col - n) + h(m + a+1, n + a+1);
                end
            end

            g(row, col) = gxy;
        end
    end

    g = uint8(g); %convert back to int
```

Here are my commands:

```
    >> img = imread('peppers.png');
    >> imshow(img)
    >> imgGray = rgb2gray(img);
    >> imshow(imgGray)
    >> 
    >> filt1 = (1/9)*ones(3)

       filt1 =

        0.1111    0.1111    0.1111
        0.1111    0.1111    0.1111
        0.1111    0.1111    0.1111

   >> test = myfilter(imgGray, filt1);
   >> imshow(test)
```

It successfully converts the colour image to grey and applies the filter.

Unfortunately, the filter just creates a nearly complete white image (too bright)... I simply can not see why... It should be taking an average of each pixel using the 3x3 filter... 
Is anything obvious to you guys to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple arithmetic typo.

`gxy = gxy + f(row-m, col-n) + h(m+a+1, n+a+1);`

Should be: `gxy = gxy + f(row-m, col-n) * h(m+a+1, n+a+1);`.

It works fine and now creates a blurry image.

Instead of multiplying `f` and `h`, they were being summed in the code above which does not conform to the spatial-domain image filter that is defined by a 2D convolution.
Matlab was executing the function correctly, however introduced anomalies(or unexpected results) even though the filter functioned correctly with a different arithmetic operator.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to see the conv2 function of MATLAB. The following function for 2D convolution has been extracted from conv2 and works great for your given filter.

```
function c = myfilter(a, b)
 [ma, na] = size(a);
 [mb, nb] = size(b);
c = zeros( ma+mb-1, na+nb-1 );
    for i = 1:mb
        for j = 1:nb
            r1 = i;
            r2 = r1 + ma - 1;
            c1 = j;
            c2 = c1 + na - 1;
            c(r1:r2,c1:c2) = c(r1:r2,c1:c2) + b(i,j) * a;
        end
    end
c = uint8(c)
```